# ImportError: cannot import name 'scan_videos' from 'subliminal'

Tags: python, module, importerror

I'm using the module `subliminal` to easily retrieve subtitles from the internet. 
The CLI works perfectly, but I cannot import it as a module in a .py file.

The simplest code ever:

```py
import os
from subliminal import scan_videos

videos = scan_videos('./')

print(videos)
```

And I always have this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "subliminal.py", line 2, in <module>
    from subliminal import scan_videos
  File "/Users/louisbertin/Desktop/videos/subliminal.py", line 2, in <module>
    from subliminal import scan_videos
ImportError: cannot import name 'scan_videos' from 'subliminal'
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I had copy-pasted the code from the documentation:

https://github.com/Diaoul/subliminal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you called your script `subliminal.py`, which makes Python find it instead of the installed module. Rename the script and you should be fine.

Comment: Yeah that's absolutely what I needed.. I ignored that Python can make a confusion with the global module. Thanks!